# How to get API response Time for each API by using selenium or python automation testing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

we got one new requirement from client that we need to capture the each API call response time to be captured through an automation testing like python or selenium. I have already tried using the requests module in python and captured the time but that API response time is not getting matched with the actual  time which is present in application (when we do network console). Could anyone suggest me how to deal with these kinds of challenges.

I have tried the below code in python:

```py
try:
    if each_api['method'].upper() == 'GET':
        start_timer = time.time()
        response = requests.get(each_api['url'], headers=req_header)  # verify=False, timeout=timeout
        latency = time.time() - start_timer
```

Answer (score 0):

check if this is of any help,

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=req_header)
print(response.elapsed.total_seconds()) # time in seconds
```